# Catch authentication exceptions

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-webflux

I use this code to send XML requests:

```
RestClient client = RestClientBuilder.builder()
                        .gatewayUrl(URL) 
                        .build();
Mono<AuthorizeResponse> result = client.executeAndReceiveAuthorize(request);
                response = result.block();

 public RestClient(String gatewayUrl, String token, String username, String password, SslContext sslContext) {
        this.token = token;
        this.gatewayUrl = gatewayUrl;
        WebClient.Builder builder = WebClient.builder().baseUrl(gatewayUrl);
        if (sslContext != null) {
            HttpClient httpClient = HttpClient.create().secure(sslContextSpec -> sslContextSpec.sslContext(sslContext));
            ClientHttpConnector httpConnector = new ReactorClientHttpConnector(httpClient);
            builder.clientConnector(httpConnector);
        }
        if (username != null && password != null) {
            builder.filter(basicAuthentication(username, password));
        }
        client = builder.build();
    }

    public Mono<AuthorizeResponse> executeAndReceiveAuthorize(AuthorizeRequest transaction) {
        Mono<AuthorizeRequest> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);
        return client.post().uri(checkTrailingSlash(gatewayUrl) + token)
                .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0")
                .accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
                .body(transactionMono, AuthorizeRequest.class)
                .retrieve()
                .bodyToMono(AuthorizeResponse.class);
    }
```

But sometimes I get this error:

```
org.springframework.web.reactive.function.client.WebClientResponseException$Unauthorized: 401 Unauthorized
 at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
2019-08-27 22:05:45,720 ERROR [stderr] (processingTransactionGenesisAuthorizeContainer-1)       Suppressed: java.lang.Exception: #block terminated with an error
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
```

How I can catch and process the exception when I get error 401?
If it's possible I would like to process the exception after the line `response = result.block();`.

Comment: Have you tried using an `onError` handler to the `Mono`?

Answer (score 2):

The very first thing is that it is not a good idea to use `block` explicitly in your reactive code. The reason behind this is, it turns the code into blocking and that is not how reactive streams are supposed to work. So, please remove `response = result.block();`

Now, if you want to process a particular status then you can modify your `executeAndReceiveAuthorize` method to use `WebClient`'s `onStatus(Predicate<HttpStatus> var1, Function<ClientResponse, Mono<? extends Throwable>> var2)`

```
public Mono<AuthorizeResponse> executeAndReceiveAuthorize (AuthorizeRequest transaction){

    Mono<AuthorizeRequest> transactionMono = Mono.just(transaction);

    return client.post().uri(checkTrailingSlash(gatewayUrl) + token)
        .header(HttpHeaders.USER_AGENT, "Mozilla/5.0").accept(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML)
        .contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML).body(transactionMono, AuthorizeRequest.class)
        .retrieve().onStatus(status -> status == HttpStatus.UNAUTHORIZED, clientResponse -> Mono
            .error(new SomeCustomAuthorizationException("Some failure exception")))
        .bodyToMono(AuthorizeResponse.class);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What about defining a [`doOnError`](https://projectreactor.io/docs/core/release/api/reactor/core/publisher/Mono.html#doOnError-java.lang.Class-java.util.function.Consumer-) on the `mono`?

For example:

```
Mono<AuthorizeResponse> result = client.executeAndReceiveAuthorize(request);
response = result.doOnError(e -> {
                      throw new RuntimeException(e);
                  })
                 .block();
```

---

Also check this [`answer`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485523/get-api-response-error-message-using-web-client-mono-in-spring-boot) in case you need access to the json response.

Comment: `doOnError` is a side effect method in Spring Webflux and should not be used for these purposes. It's more suitable for logging related works. Also, throwing exceptions is a bad idea and we should wrap exceptions like `return Mono.error(new Exception())`

Comment: The throwing of the exception is just a sample for doing something with the exception. The important part is that the exception is passed into the `doOnError` method and can be obtained from there. `@PeterPenzov` didn't really specify what he wants to di with the exception, maybe logging it is sufficient.