# Spring Boot Webclient: How to access response status reason phrase from ClientResponse

Tags: spring-boot

We are calling from our spring boot application a rest api using the `WebClient`. The rest api server logs error information in the response status reason phrase e.g.:

502 Internal Server Error (LogId=123456)

We would like to access and process the log id. But it seems there is no way to get the actual response phrase from the `ClientResponse` provided by the `Webclient` api. The `ClientResponse#statusCode` returns the status code but the response phrase is in the `HttpStatus` is [static](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/http/HttpStatus.html).

Is there any way to access the actual response phrase from the `Webclient`?

Comment: Check if this help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49485523/get-api-response-error-message-using-web-client-mono-in-spring-boot

Comment: Thank you. But the error information is in the http reason phrase part and not in the http body.